# Force dirty checking in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have an array of objects that I am binding to the DOM via a `ValueConverter`. Aurelia can't quite figure out what I'm doing in the `ValueConverter`, and so it isn't updating properly. I want to force dirty checking on this object. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expose your array via a property getter.

Instead of:

```js
export class Foo {
  myArray = [];     // will be observed without dirty-checking
}
```

Use a property getter:

```js
export class Foo {
  _myArray = [];   // internal value that you will manipulate as-needed

  get myArray() {  // this property will be dirty-checked.
    return this._myArray;
  }
}
```

Comment: a little verbose, would it be possible for us to include something in the view that flags a particular binding as dirty checkable, ala binding behaviors?

Comment: I think that would be possible- [heres](https://gist.run/?id=304cddadb7374610117a6dea2074ff5d) an *incomplete* but working prototype.  The problem is the binding system's observers are tied to object instance / property combinations and not to specific binding instances.  Multiple binding instances share observers.  For example `${foo.bar.baz} ${foo.bar.beep}` ultimately uses 4 total property observers even though there are 3 props to observe in each expression.  We'd have to do quite a bit more work to the binding behavior to make the dirty-checking binding *instance* specific.

Comment: i feel this isn't the best way to solve the actual problem i was having, probably not worth our time to try to make it work. i think a better solution would to resolve the outstanding issues with value converter. since we have no idea what information a value converter is going to use, we need a clean way to give the developer more power about when the binding recomputes. thanks!

Comment: @JeremyDanyow Could you elaborate on why is aurelia using dirty checking when using a getter compared to a property?